# Данные из формы не сохраняются в базе данных

Tags: django

Возникла проблема с добавлением объявлений от зарегистрированных пользователей: создал форму(PostForm) с наследованием от модели(Post), создал представление(create_post), шаблон. Проблема в том, что после заполнения полей формы  и нажатия кнопки "Готово", объявление не сохраняется в базе данных.
    Подозреваю, дело в том, что не задействован метод publish(), присутствующий в модели Post. Если проблема действительно в этом - как и где его вызвать?

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
action = models.CharField(max_length=7,
                          choices=(
                              ('Продам', 'Продам'),
                              ('Куплю', 'Куплю'),
                              ('Сдам', 'Сдам'),
                              ('Сниму', 'Сниму'),
                          ),
                          default='Продам')
name = models.CharField(max_length=36)
author = models.ForeignKey('registration.ExtUser')
author_id = ExtUser.id
price = models.IntegerField(null=True, help_text='RUB')
text = models.TextField()
contact = models.IntegerField(null=True)
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True)
published_date = models.DateField(
    blank=True, null=True,
)

def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

forms.py

```
class PostForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ['action', 'name', 'price', 'text', 'contact', 'category']
```

views.py

```
def create_post(request):
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    return redirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_URL, request.path))
else:
    author_id = request.user.id
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            PostForm.published_date = timezone.now()
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('myboard/home.html')
    else:
        form = PostForm()
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^new_post/$', views.create_post, name='new_post'),
```

new_post.html

```
<form action="/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>Action: {{ form.action }}</p>
        <p>Category: {{ form.category }}</p>
        <p>Title: {{ form.name }}</p>
        <p>Text: {{ form.text }}</p>
        <p>Contact: {{ form.contact }}</p>
        <p>Price: {{ form.price }} {{ form.price.help_text }}</p>
        <p>Published date: {{ form.published_date }}</p>
        <p>Author: {{ form.author }}</p>
        <p>{{ author_id }}</p>
        <form>
            <p><input type="submit" name="submitData" value="Готово" /></p>
        </form>
    </form>
```

Извиняюсь, что так много лишнего кода

Comment: Зачем вам дополнительная форма вокруг инпута? Чтобы дебажить форму можно смотреть `form.errors`, после условия `if form.is_valid()`

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, проблема в "лишних буквах". Помимо лишней формы вокруг input, не стоило указывать action в рабочей форме.